# How does Apollo-Client GraphQL refetchQueries works?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Any idea how do we get the response data from `refetchQueries`? I got the query response data from mutation.

#### Mutation

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

export const DONE_TASK = gql`
    mutation DoneTask($taskId: ID!) {
        doneTask(input: {
            taskId: $taskId
        }) {
            task {
                id
                status
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

#### Query

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

export const GET_TASKS_BY_STATUS = gql`
    query GetTasksByStatus($status: String!) {
        getTasksByStatus(status: $status) {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    status
                    description
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

#### Usage

```
const response = await client.mutate({
    mutation: DONE_TASK,
    variables: {
        taskId: 1
    },
    refetchQueries: () => [{
        query: GET_TASKS_BY_STATUS,
        variables: { 
            status: "OPEN"
        },
    }]
});

console.log(response);
```

Output

```
data: {
    doneTask: {
        task: { id:  1, status: 'DONE'}
    }
}
```

But I expect a response data from `GET_TASKS_BY_STATUS`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any queries you **re**fetch through `refetchQueries` should already be used by some `useQuery` hook, `Query` component or `graphql` HOC. In order to access the data inside the same component as your mutation, you need to utilize the query being refetched inside that same component:

```
const { data } = useQuery(GET_TASKS_BY_STATUS, { variables: { status: 'OPEN' } })
const [mutate] = useMutation(DONE_TASK,{
  variables: {
    taskId: 1,
  },
  refetchQueries: () => [{
    query: GET_TASKS_BY_STATUS,
    variables: { 
      status: 'OPEN',
    },
  }],
})
```

Comment: Oh thanks for enlightenment, This is why there is no changes because the `client.query(GET_TASKS_BY_STATUS)` is placed in a different component.

Comment: @Roel As an aside, you should avoid using `client.query` unless you need to fetch a query exactly once. If you need the query data to update when the cache updates, use `useQuery`, the `Query` component or the `graphql` HOC as indicated in the answer.

Comment: I am still in development state. At my local, I use refetchQueries. So every time I add or update, my list is refetch again. My question is that on production, other user will see the latest record that another user added. I though that in memory cache is at the client side. So how the other user will get the late record.

Comment: @AlexAung did you remember how you fixed that? I'm facing exactly the same issue

Comment: Adding my two cents: for managed class-based components, one can use `fetchPolicy: 'network-only'` for direct server queries using `client.query`. The cache will be updated accordingly. This is most appropriate for _managed_ situations (not for hooks). :)